# Why do we need apply method inside the constructor to invoke any method defined on the prototype object?

Tags: javascript

Why do we need apply method inside the constructor to invoke any method defined on the prototype object?

Code working:

```
    function Test(){
    this.x = [];
    this.add.apply(this,arguments);
    }

    Test.prototype.add = function(){
    for(var i=0; i < arguments.length; i++){
    this.x.push(arguments[i]);
    }
    }

    var t = new Test(11,12)

    t.x          //[11,12]  this is fine
    t.x.length   //2 this is also fine
```

But when i directly call add inside constructor

Code not working:

```
    function Test(){
    this.x = [];
    this.add(arguments);
    }

    Test.prototype.add = function(){
    for(var i=0; i < arguments.length; i++){
    this.x.push(arguments[i]);
    }
    }

    var t = new Test(11,12);
    t.x.length; //1 Not added all elements why?
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This hasn't got anything to do with prototypes, it's got to do with how `apply` takes an array and then uses the values as arguments to the function to call. In this case, if you do

```
this.add(arguments);
```

It's doing exactly that. Calling add with the first argument being an array-like object, and you end up with x being an array where the first element is an array. `new Test(1, 2, 3)` will result in `x = [ [1, 2, 3] ]` (the inner array is actually an Arguments object, but it resembles an array). However if you do

```
this.add.apply(this, arguments);
```

It's essentially doing

```
this.add(arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2], ...);
```

And this way x ends up being an array of those elements, instead of an array within an array. I.e., with `new Test(1, 2, 3)` you'll get `x = [1, 2, 3]`, without the extra array inbetween.